# NextJs local build and Vercel build outputs different. Any tailwind/css issue or Build issue?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I am creating building a tailwind component library where I am build few existing non-tailwind library like chakraUI, bootstrap in tailwind also with my own component library.

[image: Local Build]

But a strange problem I am facing that my sidebar is rendering properly in dev mode. Even after starting the build in local its working fine. when I am deploying it in vercel its showing the mobile view in desktop , but the mobile view its showing its not proper.

[image: Deployed Build]

I have tried it building in DigitalOcean Droplet and running it from there but its still the same issue.

This is a temporary link to sidebar and button page code.
Github: https://github.com/DebanjanT/debug/tree/main/tj

In there `sidebar.tsx` is the parent sidebar. `ChakraSidebarWrapper.tsx` is sidebar created using`sidebar.tsx` for chakraUi. `chakraButtonPage.tsx` is the actual page in nextjs as shown in picture.

Vercel Link: https://tailjet.vercel.app/

Can anyone help me why its happening? Is it any my code tailwind css issue or any build issue for nextjs.

*BTW I am using **shadcn** here.*

Thanks in advance <3.

Comment: I just found the fix , I have a folder called library where the codeblock engine file is. In tailwind It was Library. It messed up in build. OMG!